# Handling linux user password expiry from webpage

Tags: html

I am having a webpage which uses miniserv.pl as the webserver. The users that I am using to login into my webpage are linux users. Now my question is when the user password (linux user) is expired how do I handle it to change the password from the webpage. I have a "change password" page inside my website but unable to open that without authentication. 
And I don't have console access to the linux machine, Even I can't do ssh to the machine.
The only option to change the password is through webpage which is not working.
Kindly help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.